# Redux mapDispatchToProps throws TS error when rewritten from JS toTS (Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.)

Tags: typescript, redux

I have rather limited experience with TS. When rewriting perfectly working js code

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    thunkFetchIndividualBook: (redirect, id) => dispatch(thunkFetchIndividualBook(redirect, id)),
});
```

where thunkFetchIndividualBooks is as follows:

```
interface thunkFetchIndividualBookArgsType {
    redirect: RedirectType;
    id: string;
}
const thunkFetchIndividualBook = ({
    redirect,
    id,
}: thunkFetchIndividualBookArgsType): ThunkAction<void, RootStateType, unknown, AnyAction> => {
    return async dispatch => {
        const path = googleAPI + id;
        dispatch(fetchDetails(path));
        redirect.individualBook!();
    };
};

export default thunkFetchIndividualBook;
```

It tells that *Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.*
What is the problem here?

useDispatchAction is like this:

```
const useDispatchAction = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
};
```

Comment: `thunkFetchIndividualBook` in your fn declaration gets an object with `redirect` and `id` keys, whereas in your `mapDispatchToProps` they are 2 separate arguments. That's the root of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `thunkFetchIndividualBook({redirect, id})`, not `thunkFetchIndividualBook(redirect, id)`.

That said, `connect` is a legacy api and you should not be using `connect`/`mapStateToProps`/`mapDispatchToProps` nowadays unless you are working with legacy class components.

If you are using function components, please consider using the `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks instead.

Generally, if you are just learning Redux and your course is showing switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPES or immutable reducer logic, that is not part of modern Redux any more. In that case I would highly recommend you to read through [the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts). Modern Redux is just 1/4 of the code and a lot easier to use with TypeScript in specific.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. Usually I do useDispatchAction hook for props, but in this case it is a thunk which can not be handled this way ( I guess). That is why I posted the question.

Comment: No, thunks can 100% be handled by `dispatch` from `useDispatch`. It might just be missing the correct middleware types. Did you set up your `useAppDispatch` hook like in the [TypeScript quickstart](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript#define-typed-hooks)? Then it should work type-wise with `useAppDispatch` just fine!

Comment: I have added my(not mine personally, I am not the author) version of useDispatch in question.

Comment: That will probably work at runtime, but `bindActionCreators` has no knowledge of the types of `redux-thunk`, which is a different package. We really recommend using a correctly typed `useAppDispatch` (as in the docs I quoted above) to get the `dispatch` function (with thunk support) and then actually calling `dispatch(myThunk())` in your component. Generally, binding actions creators is not an encouraged style in usage with the hooks.